# How can I convert weight percentage of calcium chloride hexahydrate to calcium chloride dihydrate?

Tags: solutions, stoichiometry

I have a chemical formula with $27\%$ $\ce{CaCl2.6H2O}$ and $43\%$ water with the balance of $30\%$ being other chemicals.

I want to convert the $\ce{CaCl2.6H2O}$ and water percentage to $\ce{CaCl2.2H2O}$. I understand molecular weight percentage of $\ce{CaCl2}$ is higher in $\ce{CaCl2.2H2O}$ so I expect the percentage of calcium chloride will increase but I'm unable to calculate by how much.

Can you please show me how to calculate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you understand that you're trying to do $\ce{CaCl2.6H2O -> CaCl2.2H2O + 4H2O}$? Just assume that in the beginning you had $\pu{100 gm}$ of the total mixture. So that makes the weight of $\ce{CaCl2.6H2O}$ present in the intial mixture to be:

> $27\%$ of $\pu{100 gm = 27gm}$.

Next, calculate the number of moles of $\ce{CaCl2.6H2O}$ you had in the beginning by:

> dividing the mass you've just obtained by the molecular mass of this compound.

Now according to the stoichiometry of the reaction I've given you, when $1$ mole of $\ce{CaCl2.6H2O}$ converts, you get $1$ mole of $\ce{CaCl2.2H2O}$. Can you calculate the mass of $\ce{CaCl2.2H2O}$ thus obtained? So now you've the mass of $\ce{CaCl2.6H2O}$ *and* $\ce{CaCl2.2H2O}$.

To calculate the percentage of $\ce{CaCl2}$ in $\ce{CaCl2.2H2O}$ all you've got to do is:

> $\displaystyle \frac{\text{Mass of } \ce{CaCl2}}{\text{Mass of } \ce{CaCl2.2H2O}} \times 100\%$

You can carry out this step for $\ce{CaCl2.6H2O}$ on your own and then finally calculate the percentage change.

Comment: Hi Berry,Thank you so much for your really well laid out answer.

Comment: Hi @Berry Holmes,Thank you so much for your really well laid out answer. OK bear with me as i'm new at this. Is the number of moles of Cacl2.6H20 27/219 =0.123 ? To calculate mass of CaCl2.2H20 147 g .? therefore is the % of cacl2 in cacl2.2h20 111/147? = 75% ? And so is the % of cacl2 in cacl2.6h20 108/219 = 49.3%. So therefore75%/49.3% = 1.52. Does this mean Berry to convert 27% ofCacl2.6H20 to a % of Cacl2.2H20 = 27% * 1.52 = 41.07 % Cacl2.2h20 = 27% Cacl2.6H20 ?????. Thanks for your efforts Berry I really appreciate it  :)

Comment: @jane If your calculations are correct I see no flaw in your reasoning, and that's a good method; I hope you're getting a correct answer! Also, I'm pretty sure you're running low on time, but the next time you ask a question here please add whatever you've done (that's called showing your effort) and we'll all be glad to help you!

Comment: thank you for your reply and feedback. I still feel like I am fumbling my way through. Was my calculation figure above of 75/49,3 = 1.52 the correct figure to  convert CaCl2. 6H20 to CaCl2.2H20 ?

Comment: Thank you so much. You see even if my reasoning and hopefully  calculations are correct i dont know if they are actually correct. Hope to hear from you and sorry to waste your time Berry

Comment: @ Berry Holmes - workings : CaCl2. 2H20 =Ca - 1x40.1gm, Cl 2x35.5 = 71g, H20 =2X18 =36gm. So % Cacl2 = 71 + 40.1 / 40.1 + 71 + 36 =111.1/147.1 =75.56%

Comment: CaCl2. 6H20 = Ca - 40.1gm, Cl 2x35.5 = 71 gm, H20 = 6*18 = 108gm. So % CaCl2 = 111.1 / 40.1 + 71 + 108 = 111.1/219.1 = 50.7% (NOT 49.3 ABOVE)

Comment: Therefore 75.56/50.7 = 1.49, so to convert 27% of CACL2.6H20 to a % of CACL2.2H20 = 27% * 1.49 = 40.24%  @Berry Holmes how does this look to you ?

Comment: @jane I'm sorry for not being able to check your work right now, but please bear with me, give me a day I'll revert back once I get home.

Comment: no rush @Berry Holmes. I am looking forward to your words of wisdom